# Таблица Шульте. Нужно довести до ума

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Таблица Шульте - таблица случайно расположенных чисел, обычно размером 5x5 элементов и обычно состоит из цифр и букв.
Пример: https://cepia.ru/speedreading/schulte/.

Мне помогли реализовать таблицу. Искал информацию про все строчки кода, более менее стало понятно, но хотел бы получить разбор,чтобы точно все понять и быть готовым написать этот код самостоятельно. Пример сайта, который я использовал для поиска информации:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dockstyle?view=netframework-4.8.

Код:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Shulte
{
    class FormShulte : Form
    {
        DataGridView gv;
        Random random = new Random();

        public FormShulte()
        {
            gv = new DataGridView()
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                ReadOnly = true,
                AllowUserToAddRows = false,
                AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells
            };

            FillGrid(gv, 5, 5);
            this.Controls.Add(gv);
        }

        private void FillGrid(DataGridView gv, int width, int height)
        {
            gv.ColumnCount = width;
            var count = height * width;
            var stack = new Stack<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, count).OrderBy(x => random.Next(1, count)));

            gv.Rows.Add(height);

            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                    gv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = stack.Pop();
    }
}
        class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new FormShulte().ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Она хорошо работает, но у нее нельзя менять размер после компиляции, как сделать адаптацию таблицы под экран. В остальном, вроде, все отлично.
Теперь, осталось реализовать ходы.
Нашел пример реализации:

```cs
int hod = 1;
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
// тут если ты кликнешь по ячейки с значением которое == hod то выполняется условие
if(datagrid.rows[e.RowIndex].cells[e.ColumnIndex].value.toString()==hod)
{
//меняет значение ячейки по которой ты кликнул на слово "нашел" ты можешь что-то другое придумать
//просто очистить ячейку от значения или перекрасить ее в другой цвет. Ограничивается только твоей фантазией
datagrid.rows[e.RowIndex].cells[e.ColumnIndex].value = "нашел";
//тут каждый раз когда ты находишь число которая равняется числу hod то hod увеличивается на 1
hod++
//ну и конец если ты нашел последнее число, то есть 9 то сразу выходит сообщение "ты справился", ну и  время, сколько тебе потребовалось что бы найти все 9 чисел, думаю ты сам разберешься как добавлять секундомер в программу. 
if(hod==10)
{
messageBox.Show("Ты справился, твой результат"+time+");
}// тут если ты кликнешь по ячейки с значением которое == hod то выполняется условие
if(datagrid.rows[e.RowIndex].cells[e.ColumnIndex].value.toString()==hod)
{
//меняет значение ячейки по которой ты кликнул на слово "нашел" ты можешь что-то другое придумать
//просто очистить ячейку от значения или перекрасить ее в другой цвет. Ограничивается только твоей фантазией
datagrid.rows[e.RowIndex].cells[e.ColumnIndex].value = "нашел";
//тут каждый раз когда ты находишь число которая равняется числу hod то hod увеличивается на 1
hod++
//ну и конец если ты нашел последнее число, то есть 9 то сразу выходит сообщение "ты справился", ну и  время, сколько тебе потребовалось что бы найти все 9 чисел, думаю ты сам разберешься как добавлять секундомер в программу. 
if(hod==10)
{
messageBox.Show("Ты справился, твой результат"+time+");
}
```

После того, как получится реализовать, хотелось бы еще написать код для таблицы Шульте из букв, также изменение цвета фона таблицы.

Потом сделать меню для выбора режима. Таблица Шульте из цифр или букв.

Думаю, это будет очень хороший код для курсовой. Возможно можно добавить фигуры и иероглифы, но это уже будет лишним.

P.S Буду очень благодарен за разбор кода.

Comment: Для динамического изменения размеров контрола используются свойства Dock и Anchor

Comment: @yolosora, благодарю, а что насчет остального

Comment: Вы напрасно выбрали для реализации `DataGridView`, вам надо было создать Panel, а в нее динамически добавлять нужное количество квадратных кнопок с надписями из случ. чисел или букв из этого получилась бы таблица кнопок. И когда надо найти нужную цифру или букву в таблице, то клик по нужной кнопке эту функцию и выполнял бы. Вы ведь это в конечном счете хотите реализовать? Упражнения на быстрый поиск нужных цифр и букв для тренировки периферического зрения, не так ли?

Comment: @Bulson, да, все верно

Comment: @Bulson, код с генирацией слчайных чисел будет +- похож ? Как я понял, мне нужно будет добавить квадратные кнопки и реализовать клик по ним. Также таймер и другие мелочи.

Comment: Да, все верно, еще стоит подумать над созданием класса таблицы с соотв. свойствами и методами. А может даже создавать UserControl для каждой размерности (3x3, 5x5) c кнопками и при выборе в Combobox нужной таблицы подгружать и отображать нужную UserControl в панеле.

Comment: @Bulson Осталось все реализовать. Не могли бы вы подсказать ресурс, где 
есть вся необходимая инфориация по WinForms. На сайте от майков, информация максимально сжата и воспринимать написанное там не очень получается.

Comment: Про ресурс который вам понравится ‍♂️ может [metanit](https://metanit.com/sharp/windowsforms/1.1.php)

Comment: @Bulson, благодарю, есть над чем работать в ближайшее время

Comment: Может не сразу, но я обязан сделать это.

Comment: Ну, как говорят англосаксы you're welcome!

Comment: :).Создам новую тему, если что-то не смогу реализовать всеми усилиями, удачи вам